# Mocking winston logger in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocking, jestjs, winston

I'm thinking how to mock transports. File (from winston node module). I'm using jest so `__mocks__/winston.ts` is auto-loaded. I think that I can't mock it becouse there is `new`

```
// LoggerFactory.ts
import { transports, TransportInstance } from "winston";

...
    const transportList: TransportInstance[] = [
        new transports.File({
            name: `${tag}-error`,
            filename: `${dirname}${filename}.error.log`,
            json: false,
            level: "error",
            zippedArchive: false,
            maxFiles: 14,
            maxsize: 100000000
        }),
        new transports.File({
            name: `${tag}-info`,
            filename: `${dirname}${filename}.log`,
            json: false,
            level: "info",
            maxFiles: 10,
            zippedArchive: false,
            maxsize: 100000000
        })
    ];
...

// __mocks__/winston.ts
const winston = {
    ????
};
export default winston;
```

error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'File' of undefined

Comment: I also want to write tests for my logger implementation which uses Winston. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

For our winston test mocks in `__mocks__/winston.js`, we do:

```
const logger = {
  format: {
    printf: jest.fn(),
    timestamp: jest.fn(),
    simple: jest.fn(),
    colorize: jest.fn(),
    combine: jest.fn()
  },
  transports: {
    Console: jest.fn(),
    File: jest.fn()
  },
  createLogger: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function(creationOpts) {
    return {
      info: jest.fn(),
      warn: jest.fn(),
      error: jest.fn()
    };
  })
};

module.exports = logger;
```

We can then use the `jest.fn()` call catchers to test for the logger. Generally we don't care about logging so this is just used not to generate log files during tests.

Answer (score 0):

In your test file, type the following at the top:

```
const mockWinstonLog = jest.fn()
jest.mock('winston', () => ({
  createLogger: jest.fn(() => ({
    log: mockWinstonLog,
  })),
  transports: {
    Console: jest.fn(),
  },
  format: {
    json: jest.fn(),
  },
}))
```

You can then in your test cases check for:

```
expect(mockWinstonLog).toHaveBeenCalled()
```